# The file “NoteStore.sqlite” couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: osx-elcapitan

I am using OSx El Capitan.

Today i opened my notes app and received "The file “NoteStore.sqlite” couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format (The file might be corrupted, truncated, or in an unexpected format)"

My notes show up empty, they are all gone.

Any help to start troubleshooting will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not been there before,
[here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7528430?start=0&tstart=0) is a possible solution.